# Using .pop() for a list unless it will cause the list to be empty

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

Right now in one of my lab assignments for class, I'm using this piece of code:

```
x=0
for x in reversed(range(len(list_after_removal))):
    if guess in list_after_removal[x]:
        list_after_removal.pop(x)
        x+=1
    else:
        x+=1
```

My problem is that if the user guesses all of the vowels or maybe some other combination of letters, the list becomes empty and I get an error. Ultimately I want the program to look at what the length of the list will be with the words removed before actually removing them.

I tried something like this:

```
x=0
for x in reversed(range(len(list_after_removal))):
    if guess in list_after_removal[x] and len(list_after_removal.pop(x))>0:
        list_after_removal.pop(x)
        x+=1
    else:
        x+=1
```

But that results in a pop index out of range error. I'm not really sure how to go about implementing this.

Comment: Your code looks strange (e.g. manual modification of loop variable). Please elaborate more, what you are trying to do since this is not easily recognized from code like that.

Comment: This is a small segment of code from a hangman game I have to make for class. I have a list of words that the computer will randomly pick from for the game of hangman. Before it does that though, the computer forces the user to use up turns by removing all words from the list that contain that letter. So this small segment of code is meant to take the users guess, find all instances of it in the list, and remove them. I want it to stop before the list reaches zero, as the computer won't be able to settle on a remaining word for the rest of the hangman game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are editing the list (shortening it) as you are iterating over it. For example:

```
>>> guess = 'o'
>>> list_after_removal = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Check list_after_removal[0]: This is 'foo', and we found a match, so pop it, making list_after_removal equal to ["bar"]

Check list_after_removal[1]: Now that there is only one item in the list, this results in an IndexError!

Try this instead of the for-loop:

```
>>> guess = 'o'
>>> list_after_removal = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> without_guess = filter(lambda word: guess not in word, list_after_removal)
>>> if len(without_guess) > 0:
...     list_after_removal = without_guess
... else:
...     # Choose a word from list_after_removal because all of the words contain their guess
...     the_word = list_after_removal[0]
...
>>> list_after_removal
['bar']
```

If the lambda function is too confusing, this works too:

```
>>> guess = 'o'
>>> list_after_removal = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> def not_in(word):
...     return guess not in word
...
>>> without_guess = filter(not_in, list_after_removal)
>>> if len(without_guess) > 0:
...     list_after_removal = without_guess
... else:
...     # Choose a word from list_after_removal because all of the words contain their guess
...     the_word = list_after_removal[0]
...
>>> list_after_removal
['bar']
```

Comment: list_after_removal is a list of words. I had originally removed all words that weren't of a certain length. Now I have to remove all instances of the users guess from the list. It's meant to make the user use up guesses before settling on a random word from the list as the word for hangman. I want the program to see if removing all instances of the users guess will cause the list to equal zero. If it will equal zero, choose a random word from the remaining words in the list and continue with gameplay. If it will not equal zero, to continue removing words.

Comment: Oh, okay, I will revise my answer. Give me a moment

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been driving me insane. I know what I want it to do I just can't turn it into the correct code

Comment: Okay, take a look at it now. Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: Yeah sorry. New to the site!

Comment: No problem, I'm pretty new myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `pop` from condition also you don't need `len` because the bool value of empty list is `False` :

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([1])
True
```

So you can do :

```
x=0
for x in reversed(range(len(list_after_removal))):
    if guess in list_after_removal[x] and list_after_removal:
        list_after_removal.pop(x)
        x+=1
    else:
        x+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're popping from that list twice! Once in the `if` condition, and a second time in the next line.

Rework the condition to something like:

```
... and len(list_after_removal) > 1
```

You know that a list will be 1 item shorter after you `pop` from it, no need to actually do it in the condition.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought it was doing. But I want to know the length of the list popped, before I actually pop it. Is that possible in Python? It might not be one item shorter. I want it to remove everything that contains a certain character, but in doing so the list might become empty. I want to ensure that it won't

Comment: I don't think it would because it's removing all words that contain the guessed letter. It's meant to be a cheating version of hangman in which the computer will remove words with the guessed letter from a list, causing the user to use up turns. The computer should then settle on one of the remaining words in the list after it can't remove any more (i.e the list will reach zero).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are removing an element from the list, it will end up being an empty list. To avoid an error, you just can use `if` loop this way:

```
if list:
    list.pop()
else:
    print 'list is empty'
```

or instead, a `while`loop:

```
while list:
    list.pop()
else: 
    print 'list is empty'
```

You could also use `if len(list) > 0: ...` but this is shorter.